# Different size binlogs of galera-cluster nodes

Tags: mysql, galera, binlog

I have galera-cluster with (HA) Keepalived. I noticed that node receiving the connection from the applications has a smaller binlog.

On a node that accepts connections from applications:

```
START TRANSACTION ...
server id xxx  end_log_pos 111 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table1` mapped to number 266 (has triggers)
at 111
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 222 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table2` mapped to number 260
at 222
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 333 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table3` mapped to number 263 (has triggers)
at 333
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 444 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table4` mapped to number 276
at 444
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 555 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table5` mapped to number 351
at 555
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 666 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table6` mapped to number 311
at 666
at 777
at 888
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 777 CRC32    Write_rows: table id 266
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 888 CRC32    Update_rows: table id 263
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 999 CRC32    Update_rows: table id 260 flags: STMT_END_F ...
Number of rows: 3
at 999
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 000 CRC32    Xid = xxx 
COMMIT/*!*/;
```

On other nodes:

```
START TRANSACTION ...
server id xxx  end_log_pos 111 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table1` mapped to number 266 (has triggers)
at 111
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 222 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table2` mapped to number 260
at 222
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 333 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table3` mapped to number 263 (has triggers)
at 333
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 444 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table4` mapped to number 276
at 444
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 555 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table5` mapped to number 351
at 555
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 666 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table6` mapped to number 311
at 666
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 777 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table7` mapped to number 260
at 777
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 888 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table8` mapped to number 263 (has triggers)
at 888
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 999 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table9` mapped to number 276
at 999
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 100 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table10` mapped to number 351
at 100
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 110 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table11` mapped to number 311
at 110
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 333 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table3` mapped to number 263 (has triggers)
at 333
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 444 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table4` mapped to number 276
at 444
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 555 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table5` mapped to number 351
at 555
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 130 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table13` mapped to number 263 (has triggers)
at 130
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 140 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table14` mapped to number 276
at 140
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 555 CRC32    Table_map: `database`.`table5` mapped to number 351
at 555
at 777
at 888
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 777 CRC32   Write_rows: table id 266
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 888 CRC32    Update_rows: table id 263
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 999 CRC32    Update_rows: table id 260 flags: STMT_END_F ...
Number of rows: 3
at 999
220520 13:20:09 server id xxx  end_log_pos 000 CRC32    Xid = xxx 
COMMIT/*!*/;
```

Tables are listed. Some are listed twice or thrice.
The difference in binlog size can be x2.

Why is this happening?
How to avoid listing tables not participating in a transaction?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem.

Comment: I agree with Rick, it probably isn't a problem, it is a good opportunity for improvement if you'd like to request that [improvement](https://jira.mariadb.org). I cannot find and existing request.